# does account declared among different`#[derive(Accounts)]` struct share one storage?

Tags: anchor, account-data

When learning PDAs, I got an example that use PDAs to implement voting:
https://github.com/bfriel/crunchy-vs-smooth/blob/master/programs/crunchy-vs-smooth/src/lib.rs#L34

We can see that there are code:

```
/// The #[derive(Accounts)] macro specifies all the accounts that are required for a given instruction
/// Here, we define two structs: Initialize and Vote
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    /// We mark vote_account with the init attribute, which creates a new account owned by the program
    /// When using init, we must also provide:
    /// payer, which funds the account creation
    /// space, which defines how large the account should be
    /// and the system_program which is required by the runtime

    /// This enforces that our vote_account be owned by the currently executing program, and that it should be deserialized to the VoteAccount struct below at #[account]
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 16 + 16)]
    pub vote_account: Account<'info, VoteAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program <'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Vote<'info> {
    /// Marking accounts as mut persists any changes made upon exiting the program, allowing our votes to be recorded
    #[account(mut)]
    pub vote_account: Account<'info, VoteAccount>,
}
```

The 'vote_account' account for vote_crunchy/vote_smooth instructions is defined on `pub struct Vote{}` struct, while `pub struct Initialize{}` struct.
As to my experience on C++/Java language,  `pub struct Initialize{}` and `pub struct Vote{}` will create two variable on different memory address, so is the 'vote_account' field of these two struct.

But, from the example code, it seem that all these initialize/vote_crunchy/vote_smooth instructions operate on the same 'vote_account', it is a bit beyond my mind.

Thanks for any explains or document reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After these long days experience on contract development, I believe the answer is simple.

If `vote_account` in `Initialize` and `Vote` struct don't have any relation at all, in data address. (Though the business logic may not correct, but it does runnable)

If you call both method with same account address and this case both command will access the same piece of data.

Of course you can provide `Vote` with different `vote_account` address, as long as it have been correctly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my answer is clear.

The user - signer is paying for the creation of this account vote_account of type VoteAccount, and as u can see the VoteAccount state :

```
#[account]
pub struct VoteAccount {
pub crunchy: u64,
pub smooth: u64,
}
```

Holds information about the crunchy votes and smooth votes.

As you can see

```
   pub fn vote_crunchy(ctx: Context<Vote>) -> ProgramResult {
    let vote_account = &mut ctx.accounts.vote_account;
    vote_account.crunchy += 1;
    Ok(())
}
    pub fn vote_smooth(ctx: Context<Vote>) -> ProgramResult {
    let vote_account = &mut ctx.accounts.vote_account;
    vote_account.smooth += 1;
    Ok(())
```

when anyone will vote, it will call any of this functions, it will
change the state of the vote_account account of VoteAccount type.

Regarding the errors on the code looks like i only found one that is the space of the vote_account that is wrong should be 8+8+8 instead of 16 + 16 since its two u64 + account discriminator.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is great that you spot the error on space size.
But, what I want to know is how the 'vote_account'  in `Initialize` struct and `Vote` struct glued, ie. how does 'vote_account'   share one instance or same memory address between different struct

Comment: The Vote_account is one account created In initialize by the creator of this Voting(proposal), as you can see it has the init.

The Vote context (Vote Struct), is used during the vote_crunchy or vote_smooth.

This means that anyone that will use this vote context will change the state of that vote_account created during the initialize.

TLDR: It's only one account. That hold the information of both votes. When anyone wants to vote, it will not create new accounts everytime, it will just update the state of that account.

Comment: There missing the `index key` to retrive back the account.

We can infer that `Initialize` section create Account object for us, but what's it Unqiue ID ?

how do `Vote` section retrive this account?  is it get by 'vote_account' name ?

Also, how do we get this account in JS client side?

Comment: The account created in the Initialize section is associated with a unique address generated during its creation. . This address is usually derived using a combination of keys or seeds. And it's owned by the program.
As for the js side you can use the findProgramAddressSync to find this pda.